# Magento - Insert Alternative Store View Link in Product Page

Tags: php, magento

In my country all web stores need to be approved by government first if you want to use payment gateways. One of the rules for getting approved is not to have pictures of models on my store and since I'm selling fashion clothing, product pictures with models is a must.

A method for bypassing this limitation is to have images with models to open in a new window under a different domain name.
In terms of Magento grammar, I will upload images with models to a different store view and in the product page of my first store I will put the link of the same product in the second store view, so when customer clicks on it they can see product pictures with models on my second store view.
I want to know what the link will look like, and if its possible to have this link in a static block.